# Why doesn’t the comparator output go near the power supply voltage?

Tags: voltage, comparator

I had this circuit 
[image]

And the output voltage wasn’t the same as the supply voltage. 
I wondered that the reason was because the datasheet of the 741C says that the output shouldn’t be larger than the supply voltage. But, I wasn’t sure if this is the right reasoning?

The output voltage was between 9V and -12V depending on the potentiometer

Comment: R_s is way too small. You're overloading the output of the 741.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what was the difference between the supply voltage and the output. According to the datasheet there could be as much as 5V difference for 2kOhm load. Basically you have only 330Ohm load - assuming that the LED voltage is negligible compared to the output voltage - , so the output voltage could be even lower. 
[image]

PS: next time please rotate the picture! It would be easier to read.

Comment: I specified now the output voltage

Comment: Your specified voltages are in the range what you should expect based on the datasheet.

Comment: Is there any other reason beside the datasheet that explains why this happens?

Comment: The output driver needs some headroom. The datasheet of LM741 has a schematic in it. The VCC-VOUT difference is the required VCE of Q13 plus VBE of Q14. The very low output resistance what you are using increases these voltages. On the other hand I do not see why is it a problem, since even these voltage levels are capable to drive the LEDs. If the answer satisfy your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I think the main problem is op-amp has typical max current of 25mA and red led has a forward voltage of 1-2V and green has 2-4V which would explain the output voltage.

Comment: I don’t know why people insist on still using the 741 at all, let alone as a comparator.  There are so many better choices including actual comparators.

Comment: @JohnD I do not think they insist to use it. Many textbooks used it as an example and the easiest way to learn something is to recreate a simple circuit from a textbook. Only students are using this to try out known circuits. I am pretty sure that it will not be used for any serious designs. For educational purposes the 741 is also fine. Though I agree with you and I would advise everybody to use something more modern.

Comment: Just for reference, here is the link to the canonical question about the 741's practical limitations: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp